# In a Flex Lexer, why are last chars moved to the beginning of a buffer before loading new input?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex, lexer

I'm trying to understand a Lexer ([source](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/blob/6d135a686a74376495a7a6f55d3d67df54186f83/gramtools/mkdfa/mkfa-1.44-flex/lex.yy.c)) I'm porting to JavaScript and am stuck understanding how data from an input is read into a buffer. It's a standard Lexer so I'm hoping someone can give me some hints on what is happening on [#919](https://github.com/julius-speech/julius/blob/6d135a686a74376495a7a6f55d3d67df54186f83/gramtools/mkdfa/mkfa-1.44-flex/lex.yy.c#L919).

Snippet in question:

```
register char *dest = yy_current_buffer->yy_ch_buf;
register char *source = yytext_ptr;
...

/* First move last chars to start of buffer. */
number_to_move = (int) (yy_c_buf_p - yytext_ptr) - 1;

for ( i = 0; i < number_to_move; ++i )
    *(dest++) = *(source++);
```

I don't understand why the last characters have to be moved to the start of the buffer. I thought the buffer will be extended if I need more space than originally allocated, so why is the shuffling of last characters to the front necessary?

Plus the loop doesn't really take the buffer "current position" (my interpretation of `number_to_move`) into account. If my buffer size is 10000 and I'm at position 2048, what purpose does it serve to loop 2048x ahead of loading more data? I was also considering that if buffer-pointer `yy_c_buf_p` and input-pointer `yytext_ptr` are kept in sync, `number_to_move` would always end up being 0. But alas, maybe someone can tell me what's really happening here and what the loop actually does.

Thanks!

Comment: don't quote me on this, but I think flex is moving the not-yet-consumed bytes of the input to the start of the input, to then be able to read more input *without* having to extend the buffer, if possible, because extending the buffer as a) expensive, and b) might fail.

Comment: `*(dest++) = *(source++);` I don't believe this line is actually in the flex-code. Te parentheses are useless, and any sane programmer would use `memmove()`

Comment: @wildplasser: Flex's author, who is an excellent (and sane, if obsessed with code efficiency) programmer, doesn't use memmove because the ranges might overlap but he knows the direction to do the copy, so he can avoid the overhead of testing. He also knows that most of these moves are a handful of bytes. Actual benchmarking showed that the loop was faster.

Comment: Thanks. Aha: knowing the direction saves (at least) one test indeed. And maybe for short (unaligned) moves memcpy won't gain you anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is the shuffling of last characters to the front necessary?

It's not, strictly speaking, but it saves both time and space. When the scanner reaches the end of the buffer, the buffer looks roughly like this:

```
      already scanned tokens-----------------------Curr
      ^                                            ^    ^
      |                                            |    |
  yy_ch_buf                                   yytext    buf_p
```

Everything between the start of the buffer and `yytext_ptr` is no longer needed, and it would be a waste of time to copy it, and a waste of space to keep it around, which was important when flex was written. Instead of reallocating (unless that is really necessary because the buffer is full), the scanner can just shift the partially scanned token to the beginning of the buffer and fill the rest of the buffer from the input.

> ...  if buffer-pointer yy_c_buf_p and input-pointer yytext_ptr are kept in sync ...

Those are two different pointers, and they are only "in sync" at the beginning of a token. `yytext_ptr` (which is the internal name for `yytext`) points to the beginning of the current token; `yy_c_buf_p` points to the current position in the scan of the current token.

When end of buffer is detected, `yy_c_buf_p` points one past the NUL which terminates the buffer, so `yy_c_buf_p - yytext_ptr - 1` is the number of characters which have been scanned in the current token, 4 in the above example. (So it is the position *in the current token*, not the position in the buffer.) The next step will be to read `buffer_size - number_to_move` characters from the input so that the buffer now looks like this:

```
    Current tokenNext token-----------------------------
      | |------------read from yyin--------------------|
      ^
  yy_ch_buf
    yytext
    buf_p
```

`yytext` *must* point to the beginning of the current token, since that is the expected value of `yytext` when the action is eventually executed. `yy_c_buf_p` always points to the next character to scan, so when the end of the token is really reached, it points to the first character in the next token. (Before executing the action, that character is overwritten with a NUL, and before starting the next scan, the character is restored. That's a different part of the code, and probably unnecessary for a port to a language which doesn't use NUL-terminated strings.)

It might seem odd that the scan pointer is repositioned to the beginning of the token after the buffer is refilled, since that means that the entire token will be rescanned. This has to do with the way flex scanners recognize the end of the buffer; in summary, by the time the refill code is executed, the scanner state at the last real character scanned has been lost. The cost of keeping the old scanner state around was considered too high for the machines commonly available at the time flex was written: it would have mean an extra pointer copy in the inner scan loop, and for many machines that copy would have had to be to memory because an additional register was not available. Since the rescan occurs rarely, and since common tokens are quite short, it was considered (and tested to be) cheaper to rescan the partial token than pay the cost of keeping the state available. Whether this trade-off is correct in your application is something you will have to decide for yourself, possibly with the aid of benchmarks.

The mechanism for detecting the end of the buffer is also the reason that `yy_c_buf_p` is two bytes past the end of the partially scanned token, rather than one byte. (In the context of the flex-generated scanner, this is fine, because flex ensures that the buffer is terminated with two NUL bytes, and not just one.)

---

**Note:** Flex will resize the input buffer if it is necessary for large tokens, assuming you use the default `%p` setting. But the original lex used an *array* for the buffer (flex declaration `%a`) which could not be resized; the scanner would simply fail on very long tokens. (Since those don't happen in well-behaved code, this wasn't a problem, although it affects the way that you scan comments, for example.) So shifting the current token backwards was the only way to handle end of buffer.

Comment: Isn't the EOB marker flex uses is 2 `\0`s? If so, how does it distinguishes if I wanted to match `.*\0{2}`?

Comment: Flex uses NUL as a sentinel to indicate that it should check for EOB, not to definitively mark the EOB. That saves it from having to check for EOB on every inout character. The action corresponding to a NUL first checks if the cursor is at the buffer end; if not, it looks up and takes the transition rule for a NUL input. So you can match NULs without problems, but it will not be as fast as matching other characters. Fortunately NULs are uncommon in most lexical applications.

Comment: Sourav: I answered the question in your comment although I don't think it's really relevant to this post or my answer.

Comment: I got that doubt because you mentioned 'buffer is terminated with two NUL bytes' in your answer. Sorry, if it had to be an entirely different question.

Comment: @Sourav: the buffer is terminated with two NUL bytes; that's indicated in the flex documentation. But that does not make it a marker. C++ std::strings are always followed by a NUL character, too, but not every NUL character terminates the string.